# Let $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}.$ Define a relation $R = \{(x, y)\mid x, y \text{ even}; x, y \in X\}.$ Show that $R$ is an equivalence relation on X

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Can you help me with this problem? I have a problem demonstrating it. I know that it needs to be reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. I just don't understand when they said even, does it mean $R=\{(2,2),(2,4),(4,2),(4,4)\}?$  If yes how can I demonstrate it for example reflexive will be: for all x belongs to $X$ $(x,x)R(x,x)\rightarrow (x,x)=(x,x) ?$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: $x-y$ even does not mean $x, y$ are even. If we took $x=1, y=3$, then $x-y=-2, y-x=2$ and both are even. The reflexivity comes from this thing quite easily, as $0$ is even. Symmetry is a quick thing to check, and transitivity is the only tricky part, but can be done by writing $x-y=2m, y-z=2n$ for some integers $m, n$, and then seeing what that gives for $x-z$.

Comment: But it doesn't say "$x-y$ even".  It says "$x,y$-even" whatever that means.

Comment: @saulspatz which is an obvious typo.

Comment: Perhaps.  It's not obvious to me.  I thought it meant "$x,y even" as the OP did.

Comment: @saulspatz There are two possibilities: (1) it is a typo, and the problem can be salvaged by fixing it like that; (2) it is not a typo and the whole problem is total nonsense.

Comment: If you think it's a typo, you should say so in a comment.  I feel certain the OP could solve the problem if if it said "$x-y$ is even".

Comment: Not an obvious typo to me, either,

Comment: It was written like that why "$x,y-even" why is it a typo? and if it was x-y how should I prove it?

Comment: It's a typo because it's false that for all $x \in X$ the pair  $(x , x) \in R$ and, so, you can't prove the statement.

Comment: Probably you are just missing the equivalence relation definition. Considering it's a typo, $a R b$ if and only if  $(a,b) \in R$ if and only if $a-b$ is even. Now I suppose you got the answer.

Comment: " (1) it is a typo, and the problem can be salvaged by fixing it like that;" Fixing it to *what*; we have no idea what the author's intent was; you have a *guess* but it's just a guess.   "(2) it is not a typo and the whole problem is total nonsense" Not total nonsense... just false.  ... But in neither case are we allowed to say "I didn't like the question so I'm going to change it to something else and insist that is the answer".

Comment: Also.... for all we know the question was "Is this an equivalence relation" (in which case the the answer is legitimate, correct, ans straightforward:  No. It is not an equivalence relation)  but it was the OP assuming the question was to prove it was (which is impossible as it isn't).

Answer (score 0):

> I just don't understand when they said even,

Yeah, I don't either.  But given any option, I'd take it to mean $R= \{(x,y)| x, y$ are both even$\}$.

> does it mean R={(2,2),(2,4),(4,2),(4,4)}?

That's the only real thing that would make sense.

> If yes how can I demonstrate it for example reflexive will be: for all x belongs to X (x,x)R(x,x)→(x,x)=(x,x)?

You can't.  Because it wouldn't be true.

$1 \not R 1$ because $(1,1) \not \in R$. Nor is $(3,3)$ or $(5,5)\in R$.

So the relation just isn't reflexive.

I suspect the book has a typo and meant.

$R = \{(x,y): x, y$ are both even or are both odd$\}$.  That would be an equivalence relation with exactly to equivalet classes.

Class 1: $ \{1,3,5\}$  as all elements in the class are equivalent to each other, and Class 2: $\{2,4\}$ as all elements in the class are equivalent to each other.  Every element in $X$ is in one of the classes and the cases are disjoint and every element of $X$ belongs to *exactly* one class.

(That's not the usual definition of equivalence relation, but it is an... ahem, equivalent, definition.  It gets down to what equivalence *means* and why the text relation obviously *isn't*.  In the texts case there is only one class, the class of evens: $\{2,4\}$ and $1,3,5$ aren't in *any* class.

....

Anyway it looks like you are on top of everything and have a good grasp on everything... *except*.....

The relation is on $X$ and contains ordered pairs of $X$ but we say $xRy$ which is the same thing as $(x,y) \in R$ or if $R$ is an equivalence relationship (which it may not be) then we can say "$x$ is equivalent to $y$" or notation $x \equiv y$.

We wouldn't write, as you did when you wrote "$(x,x)R(x,x)\rightarrow (x,x)=(x,x)$", about the pairs being related.  Either the *elements* are relat**ed**, ***OR*** the ordered pairs are **in** $R$.  But not that the ordered pairs are related.